# Using IIF in SQL update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, sql-update

My existing SQL statement

```
  UPDATE EMP 
  SET fte_adj = IIf((fte<1 Or fte Is Null) And [employment category] Like '*Full-Time*',1,
IIf((fte=0 Or fte Is Null) And [employment category] Like '*Part-Time*',0.25,fte));
```

it will update table `EMP`

```
set fte_adj=1
if Full time (and fte<1 or null)

set fte_adj=0.25
if part time (and fte=0 or null)

otherwise fte_adj=fte
```

**How can I add a case to check is there any records for the employee_id exists in another table `SEC_EMP` ?**

if there is no records (0 row), then `set fte_adj=1`

both table can use employee_id as key

thanks

Comment: Have you thought of using a Case statement instead?

Comment: Where do you want to add the additional constraint?

Comment: Sorry that there is missing in my question. I need to check is there any rows for the employee_id exists in another table "SEC_EMP". is it true that i add a WHERE clause at the end that EMP.employee_id = SEC_EMP.employee_id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rewritten your statement using CASE (but I realize IIF works in 2012):

```
UPDATE EMP 
SET fte_adj = 
  CASE WHEN (FTE < 1 OR FTE IS NULL) AND [employment category] Like '*Full-Time*'
    THEN 1
  ELSE
    CASE WHEN (FTE = 0 OR FTE IS NULL) AND [employment category] Like '*Part-Time*'
      THEN 0.25
    ELSE 
      CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SEC_EMP) = 0 
      THEN 1
      ELSE 
        FTE
      END
    END
  END
```

And here is some sample [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19dfc/1).

If you prefer the IIF logic, here you go:

```
UPDATE EMP 
SET fte_adj = 
  IIF ( (FTE < 1 OR FTE IS NULL) AND [employment category] Like '*Full-Time*' , 1 ,
      IIF ( (FTE = 0 OR FTE IS NULL) AND [employment category] Like '*Part-Time*' , 0.25, 
          IIF ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SEC_EMP) = 0 , 1 , FTE ) 
          )
       )
```

And more [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a5a2/1).

**--EDIT--**

If I'm understanding latest comment, you want to update records that ONLY exist in the SEC_EMP table?  If so, just JOIN to the table as such:

```
UPDATE E 
SET fte_adj = 
  IIF ( (FTE < 1 OR FTE IS NULL) AND [employment category] Like '*Full-Time*' , 1 ,
      IIF ( (FTE = 0 OR FTE IS NULL) AND [employment category] Like '*Part-Time*' , 0.25, FTE 
          )
       )
FROM EMP E
  JOIN SEC_EMP SE ON E.employee_id = SE.employee_id
```

And more [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1bb5/1).

Comment: Sorry that there is missing in my question. I need to check is there any rows for the employee_id exists in another table "SEC_EMP". is it true that i add a WHERE clause at the end that EMP.employee_id = SEC_EMP.employee_id ?

Comment: @JoeYan -- so you only want to update records that exist in SEC_Emp -- easy enough if that's the case -- let me know and I'll update the answer using a JOIN.

Comment: @JoeYan -- I've updated my answer -- that will update only users that match in the SEC_EMP table.  Hope this helps (and that I understood your requirements correctly).

Comment: thanks sgeddes. it is true that i want to update records that ONLY exist in the SEC_EMP table.

Comment: For using CASE statement, I put the JOIN table statement after the CASE END. UPDATE EMP SET fte_adj = CASE WHEN  XXX END
FROM EMP A INNER JOIN SEC_EMP B
ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID=B.EMPLOYEE_ID

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE EMP 
SET fte_adj = CASE WHEN fte=1 Or fte Is Not Null And [employment category] Like '%Full-Time%'
THEN 1 ELSE .25 END AS 'Rate'
```

I'd also add

```
 WHERE [employment category] Like '%Full-Time%' OR [employment category] Like '%Part-Time%'
```

For safety depending on your table.  This is for MS SQL btw, no idea what '* syntax *' is from.

Comment: His current sql query is most likely for ms-access

Comment: @Lamak -- I'd guess SQL Server 2012

Comment: @sgeddes that's also an option

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `IIF`, where ever it's relevant, with an `EXISTS` statement:

```
IIF(NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT [some column] FROM [some table]
    WHERE [some condition]
), 1, [some value OR another IIF statement])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler version of the case statement from sgeddes.

```
UPDATE EMP 
SET fte_adj = 
    CASE WHEN (FTE < 1 OR FTE IS NULL) AND [employment category] Like '*Full-Time*'
      THEN 1
    WHEN (FTE = 0 OR FTE IS NULL) AND [employment category] Like '*Part-Time*'
      THEN 0.25
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SEC_EMP) = 0 
      THEN 1
    ELSE 
        FTE
    END
```

Case statements unlike IFs can have multiple branches.  They also short circuit so the first branch that get's hit is it.  So for example

```
CASE WHEN 1=1
WHEN 2=2
END
```

Will never go past the 1=1 branch.

Comment: I'd be careful about "never" - sometimes subsequent branches can be evaluated, which can affect performance, cause errors, and be unexpected if you truly believe in short circuiting. While the SQL Server documentation may lead you to believe that `CASE` is flawless here, see: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12941/does-sql-server-read-all-of-a-coalesce-function-even-if-the-first-argument-is-no/12945#12945

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking -- taking that IIF too literally :) Much better interpretation of CASE!

Comment: Excellent point Aaron.  I'll have to remember that one and change my statement to Will usually never go past the 1=1 branch :)

Comment: thanks all for your suggestion. i think i better use CASE instead of if else statement

Comment: Sorry that there is missing in my question. I need to check is there any rows for the employee_id exists in another table "SEC_EMP". is it true that i add a WHERE clause at the end that EMP.employee_id = SEC_EMP.employee_id ?

Comment: Probably should be another question but it would be WHERE EMP.Employee_Id EXISTS IN (SELECT Employee_Id FROM SEC_EMP)